# mkdir() & mkdirs() returns false

Tags: java, file

I'm creating and deleting same folder continuously as a requirement. `mkdir()` creating some times correctly but some times fails and `mkdir()` returns false.

I have searched and i got solution like change directory name before deleting. But I'm not deleting directory through android code. Deletion is done by windows side.

So, please any help.

```
      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "eTestifyData" + File.separator + orgId + File.separator +
                 providerId + File.separator + datewise + File.separator + encounterId);
        if (file.exists()) {
            write(file, file.getAbsolutePath(), jsonData);
        } else {
            if (file.mkdirs()) {
                write(file, file.getAbsolutePath(), jsonData);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Do you have permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: Yeah included ,it returns true some times,but false some times

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

> Returns: true if and only if the directory was created, along with all
>   necessary parent directories; false otherwise

So, if the directory already exists it returns false.

Comment: ok, but in my case retuning true and false,when it returns false ,it is also creating operation failed folder with orgId.

Comment: Im creating Single name directory in mobile through android and deletion is done by c#windows Side. And mkdirs() or mkdir() returns false after file deletion done by windows side . Directory name is same for creating no of times